# Why is VBO vertex size proportional to user/system CPU time usage?

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, vbo

I've written a simple benchmark to understand VBO usage.
What this does is very simple in terms of logic:

1. Loads a WaveFront Object from a file (I tested [Stanford Bunny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanford_bunny), [Stanford Dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanford_dragon) and [Happy Buddha](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/projects/large_models/happy.html))
2. Creates and initialize 3 VBOs (one for vertexes, normals and indexes)
3. Renders the scene by calling *one* time (for each *instance*):

```
    // enable states
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    // bind vertexes
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbos_[0]);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
    // normal
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbos_[1]);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
    // indexes
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbos_[2]);
    // draw n_i_ triangles using offset of index array
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, n_i_, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    // deactivate vertex array
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);            
    // bind with 0, so, switch back to normal pointer operation
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

4. The outer loop is as follows (`sceneVBO` tells how many of the same *instance* to draw):

```
    for(const auto& i : sceneVBO) {
        glPushMatrix();
            glColor3fv(i.rgb);
            glTranslatef(i.posX, 0.0f, i.posZ);
            glRotatef(angle*i.r_speed, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            vboTest->draw(); // Executes step 3
        glPopMatrix();
    }
```

5. I've started measuring the FPS and performance in general, and what I observed is that the more triangles the VBO contains, the longer the *user* and *system* time is spent during the rendering loop; please note I've measured the user/system time with [getrusage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage)

Following some reference numbers (w/u/s are the timings in *msec* for *w*all/*u*ser/*s*ystem).
For this test I've rendered 100 *instance* the very same *VBO* (i.e. `sceneVBO` contained 100 elements, all those referring to the **very same** 3 *VBOs* - vertexes, normals and indexes).

- **Bunny** `Loaded [bunny.obj] 34835/69666 (Tris/Vertexes)
  FPS: 333.3  CPU (ms/frame):  3.0/ 0.8/ 2.0 (w/u/s)  Total time (ms): 14999.5/4000.4/10000.2 (w/u/s) Frames: 5000`
- **Dragon** `Loaded [dragon.obj] 50000/100000 (Tris/Vertexes)
  FPS: 217.4  CPU (ms/frame):  4.6/ 1.4/ 3.0 (w/u/s)  Total time (ms): 22999.6/6999.7/15000.9 (w/u/s) Frames: 5000`
- **Buddha** `Loaded [buddha.obj] 543524/1087474 (Tris/Vertexes)
  FPS: 27.5   CPU (ms/frame): 36.4/10.4/26.0 (w/u/s)  Total time (ms): 181999.9/51999.8/130000.3 (w/u/s)  Frames: 5000`

Hence my question, why is VBO vertex size proportional to user/system CPU time?

I understand that if the GPU has more triangles to draw, it'll take longer, but why taking more CPU user/system time?
I'm not resending each frame the vertexes/normals nor indexes - all is *supposed* to be saved in GPU memory (array buffers are filled in with `GL_STATIC_DRAW`) - I was expecting a longer time to draw a frame, but relative less CPU usage (both user and system).

Or is it that the driver (nVidia 352.63)/GL has an active spin on `glXSwapBuffers`?

I was expecting *w*all time to increase but quite frankly **not** the *u*ser and *s*ystem time...

Ps. Of course *V-Sync* is disabled.

Comment: This is not fully modern opengl it still uses the fixed function pipeline.

Comment: It's a little bit unclear what you're asking. Are you asking, "Why does the program take longer to run if there's more triangles to draw"?

Comment: @ratchetfreak I use the fixed function pipeline for _basic_ shading and movement/rotation. I struggle to believe that this is the root cause of my CPU user/system time. Still, suppose this is true, which functions would actively block?

Comment: @Xirema Please read carefully. I'm not surprised it takes a longer **wall** time, I'm surprised it also take a toll on **user** and **system** time. That's what concerns me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested above, I've proceeded with the following:

- Ported the code to *GL* **4.5**
- Using properly  *VAO*s
- Created simple functionality to implement equivalent of `gluLookAt`, `gluPerspective`, `glColor3fv`, `glTranslatef`, `glRotatef`, `glLightfv`, ...
- Checking the above and every *single* warning/error with `glDebugMessageCallback` and `glDebugMessageControl(GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, 0, &unusedIds, GL_TRUE)`
- Ensured that the picture on screen was same as *immediate* mode

I'm still getting similar results: the larger number of triangles in my *VAO*, the longer the CPU time (both *user* and *system*) we spend inside `glXSwapBuffers`.

Which all in all seems to be quite *unexpected* (to say the least).
Of course, once *V-Sync* is enabled, the CPU time (both *user* and *system*) goes down towards ~0.

So it seems inside `glXSwapBuffers` we have an active spin directly correlated on the number of triangles to be rendered (the more triangles are to be rendered, the more CPU cycles will be burned waiting *some* event).

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things that could be suspect in your code.

You're using Immediate Mode, which means that your API calls depend on deprecated behavior which may be poorly optimized by your driver.

```
// enable states
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
// bind vertexes
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbos_[0]);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
// normal
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbos_[1]);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
// indexes
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbos_[2]);
// draw n_i_ triangles using offset of index array
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, n_i_, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
// deactivate vertex array
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);            
// bind with 0, so, switch back to normal pointer operation
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

You emphasized that this code is only called once per instance, but because of how OpenGL works—in that both it and DX9 (which is what OpenGL's immediate mode is most similar to) don't really map to the actual functionality of a Graphics Card particularly well—there's any number of things which could be happening inside these API calls used to set up state correctly. Your calls to `glVertexPointer` for example have to set up state to read from the correct segments of memory, and if your buffer object is particularly large, that could be a non-trivial operation, given that these pointers have to be set up for each thread the GPU initiates to run your shaders.

> Or is it that the driver (nVidia 352.63)/GL has an active spin on `glXSwapBuffers`?

I also wouldn't rule out this possibility. It does have to periodically query the Graphics Card to find out if the command has finished executing, so Nvidia could have chosen to implement this function as a busy wait.

The bottom line though is that if you're concerned about CPU overhead in OpenGL, you may wish to look into some [AZDO techniques](https://www.khronos.org/assets/uploads/developers/library/2014-gdc/Khronos-OpenGL-Efficiency-GDC-Mar14.pdf) (for OpenGL 4.3+), or consider learning [DirectX 12](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn899228(v=vs.85).aspx) (for Windows 10) or [Vulkan](https://www.khronos.org/vulkan/) (for anything that isn't Windows 10)

Comment: Thanks, although w.r.t. `glVertexPointer` my expectation is that the driver should tell the card `read these vertexes form that memory location you already have`. Anyway, I'll move towards using vertex and fragment shaders, removing completely the calls to `glColor3fv`, `glTranslatef`, `glPushMatrix`, ... Any other function I should remove? Btw, quite well aware of Vulkan, just stretching OpenGL to some limits to understand today's applications.

Comment: @Emanuele Use a forward-compatible OpenGL context. It'll throw errors anytime you use Deprecated functionality, which will help you weed out those calls and replace them with their modern counterparts. Also, while your expectation for `glVertexPointer` is not unreasonable, having "expectations" with openGL on how it behaves performance-wise is probably going to trip you up. As I alluded, the API is 20 years old (even the "modern" stuff is like a decade old) and many functions don't map well to the hardware of modern Graphics Cards. So weird things happen when the API lines things up.

Comment: I'll remove all immediate mode code and give it one more shot. Will keep you posted.

Comment: Added complete answer.